# Why JOGL-SWT GLCanvas is only displayed when Shell is resized?

Tags: swt, jogl

I have a JOGL 2D chart test based on SWT with four GLCanvas : legend, bottom axis, left axis and series. This component is embedded in an SWT Shell and periodically updated from a thread with generated "signals".

Here is an screen capture of the shell :

[image: Shell freshly created]

As you can see, legend, left axis and series areas are correctly updated but the bottom axis is not visible after the shell is created and this shell must be resized in order the bottom axis to be finally displayed :

[image: Shell resized]

Here is the code which display the bottom axis (text) :

```
bottomAxisAreaGLContext.getGL().getGL2().glColor3f(fontColor.getRed() / 255, fontColor.getGreen() / 255, fontColor.getBlue() / 255);
for (int i = 0; i < verticalGridLinesPositions.size(); i++) {
        int position = verticalGridLinesPositions.get(i).intValue();
        double value = (i + 1) * (windowTimeWidth) / (verticalGridLinesPositions.size() + 1);
        String valueString = decimalFormatter.format(value).replaceAll("E0$", "");
        int valueStringLength = glut.glutBitmapLength(getFontNumber(), valueString);
        bottomAxisAreaGLContext.getGL().getGL2().glRasterPos3f(position - valueStringLength / 2, getBottomAxisHeight() / 2 - getFontHeight() / 2, 0);
        glut.glutBitmapString(getFontNumber(), valueString);
}
```

A similar method is used to display the left axis.

I don't understand why the Shell must be resized for the bottom axis to be displayed.

Why does it work for all the other GLCanvases and not for the bottom axis GLCanvas ?

Any idea please ?

Comment: Just to specify that this problem does not happen on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure the Thread that updates the Shell has this structure:

```
new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                //your logic...

                display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            if (shell.isDisposed())
                                return;
                            shell.redraw();
                        }
                    });
            }
        }.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response navy1978 ! I have finally grouped every chart elements in a single GLCanvas and it works. But I still don't use this double threads "encapsulation" to update GLCanvas and I was wondering which would be the drawbacks ?

Comment: SWT is single-threaded, it means that UI objects must be accessed exclusively from a single thread (UI thread). Long-running tasks are  executed in background threads to keep the UI responsive. This makes it necessary for the background threads to enqueue updates to be executed on the UI thread instead of accessing UI objects directly."
So if you update your canvas within the UI thread you don't need the "double threads encapsulation" but if you update your GUI from another Thread you have to use it.